# front end code converter for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, oracle, visual-studio-2008

I have been assigned a task to migrate database from sql server to Oracle. At the back end am using Sql Developer which does 80% work for me but when it Comes to front end which is in asp.net and the language am using is VB I am unable to perform complex things like writing the code for XML files.

for example

```
 Ccomm = Trim(Ccomm) & "<Ccomm Type = """ & Typecode(1).Trim & """ Relation=""" & Relation(1).Trim & """ RatePlan1= """ & Rcode1(1).Trim & """ Rate1 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("Rate1"))) & """ Dental1 = """ & dcode1(1).Trim & """ Optical1 = """ & ocode1(1).Trim & """ Maternity1 = """ & mcode1(1).Trim & _
              """ RatePlan2= """ & Rcode2(1).Trim & """ Rate2 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("Rate2"))) & """ Dental2 = """ & dcode2(1).Trim & """ Optical2 = """ & ocode2(1).Trim & """ Maternity2 = """ & mcode2(1).Trim & _
              """ RatePlan3= """ & Rcode3(1).Trim & """ Rate3 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("Rate3"))) & """ Dental3 = """ & dcode3(1).Trim & """ Optical3 = """ & ocode3(1).Trim & """ Maternity3 = """ & mcode3(1).Trim & _
              """ RatePlan4= """ & Rcode4(1).Trim & """ Rate4 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("Rate4"))) & """ Dental4 = """ & dcode4(1).Trim & """ Optical4 = """ & ocode4(1).Trim & """ Maternity4 = """ & mcode4(1).Trim & _
              """ RatePlan5= """ & 0 & """ Rate5 = """ & 0 & """ Dental5 = """ & 0 & """ Optical5 = """ & 0 & """ Maternity5 = """ & 0 & _
              """ RatePlan6= """ & 0 & """ Rate6 = """ & 0 & """ Dental6 = """ & 0 & """ Optical6 = """ & 0 & """ Maternity6 = """ & 0 & _
              """ DentalRate1 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("DentalRate1"))) & """ DentalRate2 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("DentalRate2"))) & """ DentalRate3 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("DentalRate3"))) & """ DentalRate4 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("DentalRate4"))) & """ DentalRate5 = """ & 0 & """ DentalRate6 = """ & 0 & _
              """ OpticalRate1 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("OpticalRate1"))) & """ OpticalRate2 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("OpticalRate2"))) & """ OpticalRate3 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("OpticalRate3"))) & """ OpticalRate4 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("OpticalRate4"))) & """ OpticalRate5 = """ & 0 & """ OpticalRate6 = """ & 0 & _
              """ MaternityRate1 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("MaternityRate1"))) & """ MaternityRate2 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("MaternityRate2"))) & """ MaternityRate3 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("MaternityRate3"))) & """ MaternityRate4 = """ & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("MaternityRate4"))) & """ MaternityRate5 = """ & 0 & """ MaternityRate6 = """ & 0 & """ />"
```

this whole XML code is for sql server.And the same code I need to write it for Oracle and 80% web forms of my application use xml.So, is there any front end code converter or i have to do it manually ? I am using Visual Studio 2008.Please help me out I am a beginner.Thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly is your question? How to handle xml in oracle?

Comment: Yes.And also is there any tool to convert  the code in front end.Because i have so many web forms and each form has alot of xml code.

Comment: If the code is written well then there are no front end changes required. Just swap out the SQL component for the Oracle one

Comment: When you are saying Sql Component what is your scope ? is it just up to swapping queries,stored procedures and their related parameters ? If it is just limited till there then yeah I swapped all the sql server queries with those of oracle.But,it doesn't end here if you are using XML in your SQL Server stored procedure right ? At application level syntax for calling XML is different for both sql and oracle.I used the below syntax for oracle and it worked

Comment: Ccomm = Trim(Ccomm) & "<Ccomm><Type>" & Typecode(1).Trim & "</Type><Relation>" & Relation(1).Trim & "</Relation><RatePlan1>" & Rcode1(1).Trim & "</RatePlan1><Rate1>" & Val(obj.ConValue(DR.Item("Rate1"))) & "</Rate1><Dental1>" & dcode1(1).Trim & "</Dental1><Optical1>" & ocode1(1).Trim & "</Optical1><Maternity1>" & mcode1(1).Trim & "</Maternity1>.................................</Ccomm>"